# Customize appearance of listview's items

Tags: android, listview, textview

I implemented a ListView for showing book's text. So that every paragraph of text is a item (TextView) in the ListView. But I don't want to items be distinguished from each other when they focused or selected and click on them.
So, I used `<selector>` for ListView; But I could just customized background of items!

Now, If I want to customize foreground of list items like text color, what should I doing?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own xml layout for list items and put it into your adapter. For example, for `SimpleAdapter` the constructor would look like this:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, list, R.layout.your_item_style, from, to) // where "your_item_style" is name of xml file in layout folder of your app
```